# PowerShell 2 - How To View User Accounts That Have Been Inactive For 90 Days

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am limited to PowerShell Version 2.

I am trying to list out user accounts that have not logged in for more than 90 days.

I have been trying to craft the command for this but have failed, so far I have managed to craft the following:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount=True" | Where-Object { (New-Timespan -Start $_.LastLogon -End (Get-Date)).Days -ge 90 }
```

Can you please help me? :)

Comment: Local accounts, or domain accounts? Are you really using PowerShell v2?

Comment: Local accounts and yes, I am limited to PS v2, working on older systems.

Comment: Please, don't tell me you will be going computer by computer running this script....

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon no, I need to run this on one system :)

Comment: Working with unsupported systems because some penny-pinching $reason not to upgrade is fool's errand. Anyway, look for a VBScript solution. Those should give you pointers to WMI and ADSI options, which can be transformed to Powershell without too much of a hassle.

Comment: @vonPryz Using old systems due to application compatibility...how does one use VBScript? I have never used it, Are there no other methods of getting this information from PS?

Comment: There isn't a need to execute VBScript, only find solutions written in it. Look which WMI classes and ADSI providers are queried and convert the methods into Powershell.

Comment: I have run multiple tests and have researched online, I have not been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PowerShell version 2, you could use `Adsi` like below:

```
function Get-LocalUsers {
    Param([string]$ComputerName=$env:COMPUTERNAME)

    [ADSI]$computer="WinNT://$ComputerName"

    $computer.PsBase.Children | Where-Object {$_.SchemaClassName -match "user"} |
    Select-Object @{Name="ComputerName"; Expression={$computer.Name}},
                  @{Name="User"; Expression={$_.PsBase.Properties.Name.Value}},
                  @{Name="Description"; Expression={$_.PsBase.Properties.Description.Value}},
                  @{Name="Disabled"; Expression={[bool]($_.PsBase.Properties.Item("userflags").Value -band 2)}},
                  @{Name="LastLogin"; Expression={ if ($_.PsBase.Properties.LastLogin.Value) {
                                                        [datetime]$_.PsBase.Properties.LastLogin.Value
                                                   } else { "Never" }}}
}

# set the date to compare against to midnight using '.Date'
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90).Date
Get-LocalUsers | Where-Object { $_.LastLogin -eq 'Never' -or $_.LastLogin -lt $refDate }
```

Comment: Hi Theo, thank you, I really appreciate the response! I have run a few tests with the provided code and it seems to not output any data, even if I change the -90 to -1 for testing purposes. Do you know what may be wrong?

Comment: @Help what do you get if you comment out the final `Where-Object`?

Comment: Thank you for the hint, it is now working as expected, the issue was related to the format when I pasted it in. You are a legend!

Comment: Hi Theo, once again, thank you so much for helping with this! Is there a way to enhance the command to also match users where the paramter "Last Logon" is set to "Never"?

Comment: @Help See the edit on `@{Name="LastLogin"`. Cheers ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @Theo, the else statement was missing another } at the end, other than that, seems to be working perfectly!

Comment: @Help Ah... copy\paste error. I have added the missing `}` now